# Pass a splatted param list to a nested function

Tags: ruby

I have a set of nested functions that each take an arbitrary list of arguments:

```
def foo *args
  bar args
end

def bar *args
  baz args
end

def baz *args
end
```

Calling foo with a set of args like `:a => :foo, :b => :bar` gives us a single element array after the splat:

```
[{:a => :foo, :b => :bar}]
```

And then passing that along to the nested function, and again through a splat, makes for this:

```
[[{:a => :foo, :b => :bar}]]
```

Is it appropriate to pass args[0] along to the nested function, or is there some kind of reverse splat that I should be using instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to relay splatted arguments to another function, just splat them again (the operator behaves the opposite way when used in a method call (vs. method definition))

```
def foo(*args)
  bar *args
end
```

Comment: @kid_drew: ruby is full of quirks. You'll get used to it. :)

Comment: Quirky yes, but it does so many things SO well.  I come from the PHP world, so I'm digging it.